# Creating a custom dialog that returns parameters

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I just want to create an small application which opens another dialog when button is pressed. Below is the code for the dialog box.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(508, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 250, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 120, 181, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.sl_value = QtGui.QSlider(Dialog)
        self.sl_value.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 120, 161, 31))
        self.sl_value.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.sl_value.setObjectName("sl_value")
        self.ed_value = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.ed_value.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 120, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.ed_value.setFont(font)
        self.ed_value.setObjectName("ed_value")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"), Dialog.accept)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("rejected()"), Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)


    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Set example value:", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

And in main file i have added following code segment

```
class StartSub2(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

dlg = StartSub2()
if dlg.exec_():
   values = dlg.getValues()
```

The dialog is opened whenever button is pressed but the dialog is completely empty none of the elements are shown.
So how to make element visible in dialog???
But when i try to import dialog file in main file I am getting error

```
  cannot import name Ui_Dialog
```

Comment: You could show an image of what you get

Comment: The code you've posted works perfectly fine for me. All I had to do was add `app = QtGui.QApplication([])` before creating the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Using PyQt5 (sorry). First, the ui definition:

```
# file ui_dialog.py

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(508, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 250, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.sl_value = QtWidgets.QSlider(Dialog)
        self.sl_value.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 120, 161, 31))
        self.sl_value.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.sl_value.setObjectName("sl_value")
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
```

and in the same directory, the application definition:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog)
from ui_dialog import Ui_Dialog


class StartSub2(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self,parent)

        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.values = dict(slider=None)

        self.slider = self.ui.sl_value

        # connect the valueChanged signal to the update_slider slot
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.update_slider)

    # slot
    def update_slider(self, val):
        self.values['slider'] = val


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = StartSub2()
    if dialog.exec():
        slider_value = dialog.values['slider']
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: you're very welcome. I hope it helps! if the answer is sufficient enough, please consider marking it as correct. appreciate it!